# How to remove vb.net Richtextbox lines that not contains specific words

Tags: vb.net

Hi there im trying to get specific words from a html web page and im trying to do this by loading the html sourcecode into a textbox and then filter it out.

Im now using this wich is stupid i know but how can i fuse both together that it will check both words in 1 loop?

```
    Dim Filter1 = "filterword1"
    Dim Filter2 = "filterword2"


    TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText
    TextBox2.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    lines = TextBox1.Lines.ToList
    For i As Integer = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not Regex.IsMatch(lines(i), Filter1) Then
            lines.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next

    TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray


    Dim lines1 As New List(Of String)
    lines1 = TextBox3.Lines.ToList
    For i As Integer = lines1.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not Regex.IsMatch(lines1(i), Filter2) Then
            lines1.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next

    TextBox1.Lines = lines1.ToArray
```

Comment: Try use foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I got it working :

```
Const filter = "(Filterword1)|(Filterword2)|(Filterword3)|(Filterword4)"
   Dim lines As New List(Of String)
        lines = TextBox2.Lines.ToList
        For i As Integer = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Not Regex.IsMatch(lines(i), filter) Then
                lines.RemoveAt(i)
            End If
        Next
```